# Send mail transparent for user

Tags: android, email

I have an service where some data is sent periodically to a contact. Before starting this service, the user must set in the mainActivity the contact's phone number and email, and then select the communication mode between SMS and eMail.

Once the service is started, the user can close the app, the service will run in background.

Sending SMS from the service is not trouble, but sending the eMail requieres a prompt with the email client chooser to be shown, and this operation must be transparent for the user.

This is the way I configure the email intent.

```
Intent mailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
mailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
mailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {email});
mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, R.string.email_subject);
mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, location_link);
```

Could be a way to select the email client before starting the service, and then pass it to the intent? this way the chooser won't be shown.

Comment: you can send email using smtp

Comment: try to use javax.mail to send mails in the background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible by writing your own Mail Sender class

```
public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator 
{   
private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";   
private String user;   
private String password;   
private Session session;   
private Multipart _multipart;

static 
{   
    Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());   
}  

public GMailSender(String user, String password) 
{   
    this.user = user;   
    this.password = password;   

    Properties props = new Properties();   
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
    props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);   
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");   

    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
    _multipart = new MimeMultipart();
}   

protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() 
{   
    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);   
}   

public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception 
{   
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   
    DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));   
    message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
    message.setSubject(subject);   

    message.setDataHandler(handler);   
    message.setContent(_multipart);
    if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
    else  
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   
    Transport.send(message);   

}   

public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception 
{
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
}

public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource 
{   
    private byte[] data;   
    private String type;   

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) 
    {   
        super();   
        this.data = data;   
        this.type = type;   
    }   

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) 
    {   
        super();   
        this.data = data;   
    }   

    public void setType(String type) 
    {   
        this.type = type;   
    }   

    public String getContentType() 
    {   
        if (type == null)   
            return "application/octet-stream";   
        else  
            return type;   
    }   

    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException 
    {   
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);   
    }   

    public String getName() 
    {   
        return "ByteArrayDataSource";   
    }   

    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException 
    {   
        throw new IOException("Not Supported");   
    }   
}
```

}

and

```
public final class JSSEProvider extends Provider 
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public JSSEProvider() 
{
    super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
    AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() 
    {
        public Void run() 
        {
            put("SSLContext.TLS",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
            put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
            put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
            put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
            return null;
        }
    });
}
}
```

You would be requiring [activation.jar](http://javamail-android.googlecode.com/files/activation.jar), [additionnal.jar](http://javamail-android.googlecode.com/files/additionnal.jar) & [mail.jar](http://javamail-android.googlecode.com/files/mail.jar) files

Comment: Then, the user at app's first start should introduce his email account and pasword, right? How would I call the send method form the service where I define the email's subject and text?

Comment: I think user will not be happy to provide its own username ans password , launching mail using Gmail App in background is not possible it can only be fired from intent.

Comment: No, I think I haven't explined well. I mean that i'm not sure on how to inplement your code. Where is called GMailSender() method? Also, where do I indicate the eMail's subject and text?

Comment: Same as  sending of SMS which works fine for you according , you can provide subject and text in same way and you can call this in Async in Service if no user Interaction needed .

Comment: Could you add an example of this implementation?

Comment: Go through this toutorial
http://www.androiddevelopersolutions.com/2014/06/android-send-emails-android-send-emails.html